# dev board with 3 or more mipi-csi

Tags: video-camera, embedded-systems, microcontroller

I'm looking for "NVIDIA Jetson TX1" module alternatives for 360 video capturing

main requirements - 3 or more 4 line mipi-csi with ability to transfer 4k from each camera and sata or 10g ethernet phy to transfer video to storage.
Also size, weight and price should be minimal.

any suggestions?

Comment: I do not think you'll get any such thing from a development board. What you're asking for is something that most modern day PCs still aren't capable of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I was looking for the same requirement last month, I found e-con Systems who make cameras for NVIDIA Jetson TX1. They have a 360degree solution for TX1. I can see that they run 6 MIPI CSI-2 Cameras simultaneously. Please refer : https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/camera/?p=1709